# How to update the index in Lucene

Tags: lucene

I am using Apache Lucene and my Database is approx 3 GB.

While I create index using Lucene first time it will take approx 25 min. But i want my application like it will update every time when am using it.

So how can I do these thing so my index can update every time and while updating it will take less time?

Database changes are very less but new entry of database should be indexed.

```
Directory directory = new SimpleFSDirectory(INDEX_DIRECTORY);
        //Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);
         SimpleAnalyzer analyzer = new SimpleAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);  
           IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_36, analyzer);
           indexWriterConfig.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE);
           IndexWriter iWriter = new IndexWriter(FSDirectory.open(indexDirNEW), indexWriterConfig);
        IndexWriter iWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, true,MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);



        int count = 0;
        while(rs.next()) {
            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.add(new Field("NAME", rs.getString("NAME")==null?"":rs.getString("NAME"), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED ));
            doc.add(new Field("CUSTOMER", rs.getString("CUSTOMER")==null?"":rs.getString("CUSTOMER"), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED ));
            iWriter.addDocument(doc);
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println(count+" record indexed");
        iWriter.optimize(); 
        iWriter.commit();
        iWriter.close();
```

Comment: The most obvious speed up would be to not call optimize(). Have you profiled your code to see where your execution time is spent?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd recommend you upgrade Lucene.  Significant performance improvements have been introduced since 3.6.  (for instance, [Mike McCandless writes about a 256% speedup in indexing using Lucene 4.0 features](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/05/265-indexing-speedup-with-lucenes.html)).

---

Aside from that, you might gain a lot by optimizing the code in your loop.  You don't actually need to instantiate new Documents or Fields, you can just update their values.

Referring to the columns by index, instead of by name should save a bit.  Also, you could eliminate the multiple calls to `ResultSet.getString` and assign them to strings instead.  Not sure how significant those will prove to be in your case.

```java
final int NAME_INDEX = 1;
final int CUSTOMER_INDEX = 2;

//Setup document
Document doc = new Document();
Field nameField = new Field("NAME", "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
doc.add(nameField);
Field customerField = new Field("CUSTOMER", "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
doc.add(customerField);

int count = 0;
while(rs.next()) {
    String name = rs.getString(NAME_INDEX);
    String customer = rs.getString(CUSTOMER_INDEX);
    nameField.setValue(name == null ? "":name);
    customerField.setValue(customer == null ? "":customer);
    iWriter.addDocument(doc);
    count++;
}
```

Doing some testing, these tweaks seemed to save about 20% on time for my tests to complete.  Not inconsiderable, but again, upgrading Lucene will likely get you more.

Also, couldn't hurt to make sure it has enough memory.  If it starts thrashing while trying to index and optimize all that data, performance will go through the floor.

There are some other tips that might be worth looking into here:  [How to make searching faster](https://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveSearchingSpeed).

Answer (score 0):

If your Lucene Indexing code is disconnected from your main application that uses DB and is running as separate Job during some low time, then you need to introduce two modes in your job - **Incremental Mode** and **Full Indexing Mode**.

I have one such set up and I have basically made SQL query which selects table data to index to be configurable via configuration parameters and properties so I build select query at run time using parameters passed.Disadvantages of this approach being the time frame when DB & Index are out of sync ( that depends on Job run frequency ) and manual job parameter changes. I try to reduce out-of-sync issue by doing incremental indexing first in searcher applications.

Second approach would obviously be to kick off your indexing code every time some application updates DB.

In my case, lucene searcher applications update DB so I update lucene index immediately from there because I know all the details about updated records.

I have implemented most of improvements listed here - [How to make indexing faster](https://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveIndexingSpeed). Few suggestions are not relevant for recent lucene versions.

Also, see if you are over indexing i.e. indexing data not needed by searcher applications.

Reengineering SQL select queries was another improvement area for me as I had 200 million plus rows and selecting data fast was core area.

Usage of DB Connection pools and using same writer instance from multiple Java threads had improved speed further ( since lucene writer is thread safe ). I keep DB connections and number of threads configurable. So I distribute my indexing load to multiple threads. Also, I commit on large chunks of data but open and close writer only once.

Implement other suggestions listed in femtoRgon's answer and comment. As per my experience, improvement is going to be a gradual process and you will not achieve everything in first shot.